# MySQL Arrays: Can this be done?

Tags: mysql, arrays, subquery, concatenation

Is it possible to select the concatenation of all the results returned by a subquery?

So if the subquery returns more than one row, I can somehow get all the results contained in a single string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sort* of. What you can get is the concatenated result of all the rows that were grouped together using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). You could use that to employ `GROUP BY` by a column that you know would group the result set correctly and then using the function to return the concated groups. The manual page should provide some examples.

Comment: That is great! I can just `GROUP BY 1` to get all the results grouped into a single row. Thanks!

Comment: Note that *The result is truncated to ... `group_concat_max_len` ..., which has a default value of 1024.* This is trivial to increase, either system-wide, or on a per session basis with *`SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = val;`*

Answer (score 1):

Some MySQL clients, such as the MySQL Command-Line tool, can export the result set in various formats, such as XML.

If you're using a programming language that implements the MySQL client/server protocol through some type of API, it seems like building the array would be trivial in code. PHP's MySQL API returns results in an array.

If you're talking about grouping multiple rows in a result set into a single row, then take a look at [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: **1.** No, not using command line here, just everyday programming. **2.** Yes, definitely trivial, but many things you can do in the programming language, can be moved into the original SQL statement, which can improve efficiency some of the time, and shorten and simplify the code other times. **3.** Definitely what I am after, though your answer was 36 minutes later. +1 anyway.