# running a query with tables listed in an array

Tags: php

I need to run a mysql query that selects records from several tables. the names of the tables are received via post and are stored in an array.
What I have done is this that does not work:

```
//--> Check if anything is posted from the client
if(isset($_POST['code'])){

    $emps = array();

    foreach(($_POST['code']) as $c) {
        $emps[] = $c;
    }

    @$res = mysql_query("select code,fname,faname from (".implode(',',$emps).")") where emp_code='11330' ;

    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        //do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for starters, remove the error suppressor for the query and see why it's not working.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Passing table names in post/get is a terrible idea..

Comment: dont use @ operator to ignore error its always bad you must solve them

Comment: For security reasons filter, the posted data like this:
`$allowedTables = array(/*list of the allowed table names*/); $emps = array_intersect($_POST['code'],$allowedTables);` 
What you want is a bit complicated. Do you need `UNION` or `JOIN` the results ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
mysql_query("select code,fname,faname from (".implode(',',$emps).")") where emp_code='11330' ;
```

with

```
mysql_query("select code,fname,faname from (".implode(',',$emps).") where emp_code='11330'") ;
```

Comment: I expect this error: #1052 - Column 'emp_code' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: you need to write it like this then tablename.emp_code
and moreover I guess you should be using joins in it

Comment: I guess you know Joins :
just go through it,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($emps);$i++)
  {
      $query=$query."select code,fname,faname from ".$emps[$i]." where 
         ".$emps[$i].".emp_code='11330' UNION " ;
  }

     @$res=mysql_query($query);
```