# fetch rows from two different table on MySQL without any relation between both tables

Tags: php, mysql

There is two tables there is nor relation between both tables,

structure: table_one

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
| name    | age    |insertTEMP |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| cat     | 12     |02-02-2014 |
| dog     | 13     |03-04-2014 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

structure: table_two

```
+---------+--------+---------------+
| book    | pages  | insertTEMP    |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| book1   | 34     | 05-02-2014    |
| book2   | 54     | 04-03-2014    |
+---------+--------+---------------+
```

now the idea is here i want to list records from both table so i keep bellow function to list them.

```
public function recentALL() {
   $sql = "select * from table_one, table_two ORDER BY insertTEMP";
    $q = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
    $q -> execute();
    return $row = $q -> fetchAll();
 }
```

and i fetch it in the view,

```
        $data2 = $functions->recentAll();
            foreach ($data2 as $data3){
                  echo $data3['name']  . $data3['book'] . '<br />';

           }
```

how i can make it to show like:

```
+---------+--------+
| cat     | NULL   |
| null    | book1  |
| null    | book2  |
| dog     | null   |
+---------+--------+
```

this based on the **insertTEMP**

Comment: Sidenote: You do realize that `insert` is a MySQL reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: that was only temp question i understand the keywords.

Comment: Pretty sure you can use UNION http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: Try a query like -> `SELECT name, NULL as book, insertTEMP FROM table_one UNION SELECT NULL as name, book, insertTEMP FROM table_tow ORDER BY insertTEMP`

Comment: What do you mean by "based on insertTEMP"? How does `insertTEMP` affect your results?

Comment: i mean i will sort it ORDER BY insertTEMP, here when i use union it works but when i add order by too it' gives error

Comment: @Fred-ii- THANKS it's help me to fine way out of it.

Comment: @abas_rafiq You're quite welcome.

Comment: This is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
Select * from (
    Select name  as Name, null as Book,insertTEMP  from table_one
    UNION ALL
    select null as Name, book as Book,insertTEMP  from table_two
) as tmp
Order by tmp.insertTEMP asc
```

Change the column names in your code as per query