# Sort multiple Mysql queries by common field

Tags: mysql

I'm new at this and don't comprehend Mysql very well.  I'm trying to retrieve ALL media uploaded by a certain user, and sort it all by the date it was uploaded.  Problem is, the media is in 3 different tables.  Can someone provide me with a good solution?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE user_id = $user_id";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user_id = $user_id";
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM audios WHERE user_id = $user_id";

SORT DESC BY $result['upload_date'];
```

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql

Comment: good info there, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a `JOIN`. If you only want rows where there are existing relationships, you can use an inner join, set up like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM videos v
JOIN photos p ON p.user_id = v.user_id
JOIN audios a ON a.useR_id = p.user_id
ORDER BY upload_date DESC;
```

The above will select all columns, which may have some repeated things. For example I believe `user_id` will show up once for each table you joined, so I would narrow down your select clause.

Comment: Thanks.  Good point on the dupe user_id, I'll narrow down the select statement as suggested.