# multiple query same table but in different columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get more columns summarizing the result from 2 different tables

```
SET @start_res = 20150301;
SET @finish_res= 20150501;
SET @finish_check= 20150801;
SET @start_check= 20150301;
SET @daily_hos= 3;

SELECT* from
   ( SELECT COUNT(DAY_IN) AS arr FROM t_hospital WHERE DAY_IN between  @start_check and @finish_check and RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos group by DAY_IN  )e,
     (SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS ONG1 FROM t_hospital WHERE PAT_STATUS  like '%ong%' and  DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos group by DAY_IN ) a,
        (SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS RTED FROM t_hospital WHERE PAT_STATUS  like '%rtde%'and  DAY_IN between  @start_check and @finish_check and RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos group by DAY_IN  )b,
           (SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS POLI FROM t_hospital WHERE PAT_STATUS  like '%pol%'and DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos group by DAY_IN   )c,
              (SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS para FROM t_hospital WHERE PAT_STATUS  like '%para%' and  DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos group by DAY_IN  )d
```

and of course it does not work, just the first displayed column (arr) works while the other ones show a wrong output.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT \* FROM multiple tables. MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql) ... You need to join these tables together.

Comment: Your tables e, a, b, c, d does not *join* each other

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty common pattern:

```
SELECT DAY_IN, COUNT(*) AS arr,
        SUM(IF(PAT_STATUS  like '%ong%', 1, 0)) AS ONG1,
        SUM(IF(PAT_STATUS  like '%rtde%', 1, 0)) AS RTED,
        SUM(IF(PAT_STATUS  like '%pol%', 1, 0)) AS POL1,
        SUM(IF(PAT_STATUS  like '%para%', 1, 0)) AS para
FROM t_hospital 
WHERE DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check 
    and RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  
    and ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos
GROUP BY DAY_IN
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005+, you can use Window functions.
But it isn't supported in MySQL.

In Subquery, select statements must have join operator. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT COUNT(..) ...) AS C1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(...) ...) AS C2
            ON <condition>
       INNER JOIN ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SET @start_res = 20150301;
SET @finish_res= 20150501;
SET @finish_check= 20150801;
SET @start_check= 20150301;
SET @daily_hos= 3;

SELECT 

(SELECT COUNT(DAY_IN) AS arr FROM t_hospital WHERE 
DAY_IN between  @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) e,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS ONG1 FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%ong%' and  
DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) a,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS RTED FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%rtde%' and  
DAY_IN between  @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos)b,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS POLI FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%pol%' and 
DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) c,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) AS para FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%para%' and  
DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) d
```

Your question mentions about joining 2 tables but there appears to be only `t_hospital` in question. You might want to update your question with information about the other table.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, here's what you want.

```
SET @start_res = 20150301;
SET @finish_res= 20150501;
SET @finish_check= 20150801;
SET @start_check= 20150301;
SET @daily_hos= 3;

SELECT 

(SELECT COUNT(DAY_IN) FROM t_hospital WHERE 
DAY_IN between  @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) AS 'arr' ,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%ong%' and  
DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) AS 'ONG1' ,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%rtde%' and  
DAY_IN between  @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) AS 'RTED' ,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%pol%' and 
DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) AS 'POLI' ,

(SELECT COUNT(PAT_STATUS) FROM t_hospital WHERE 
PAT_STATUS  like '%para%' and  
DAY_IN between @start_check and @finish_check and 
RES_DATE between @start_res and @finish_res  and 
ID_daily_hos =@daily_hos) AS 'para'
```

Comment: This did not work for me.