# Mysql query for grouping data using two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below data table and need to accomplish the result for Student count as per availability and per department

[image]
Note: Different Department may come in later.

[image]

Want to have result as below: (Student count as per availability and per department)
[image]

Comment: Use a subquery to calculate the count per department and availability. Then combine those counts using `GROUP_CONCAT` in the main query.

Comment: Do you really want `Yes, 2, No, 3` as a value in a column? I'd recommend just having 3 columns.

Comment: Why does the first table have the department name instead of ID?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139000/multiple-query-same-table-but-in-different-columns-mysql/33139182#33139182

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get count  by `department,studavailablity` on a subquery.then use `GROUP_CONCAT` function to create the *studCount* by subquery.

If you want to show `Yes` in front of `No` you could Add `order by` on `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

You can try this.

```
SELECT department,GROUP_CONCAT(Concat(studavailablity,' ',c) order by 1 DESC)  'count'
FROM(
  SELECT count(1) c,department,studavailablity 
  FROM T
  GROUP BY studavailablity,department
) t
group by department
order by department desc
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4e56f/16*

Answer (score 0):

How about `SELECT Department, Studavailability, COUNT(*) FROM students GROUP BY Department, Studavailability;`?  Best of luck!

Comment: something like Electronic |  Yes,2  | No,3 will also work .

Comment: This will get `Yes` and `No` on different rows of the result, not the same row as he wants.