# SQL - Combine two COUNT with different WHERE causes and GROUP BY the users names

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying hard to find a solution to this one but I can't see a way to do it.

I am inserting kills made in a game and I am recording the killer, his clan, the victim and the victim's clan so my database looks like this,

```
killer | killerClan | victim | victimClan
-----------------------------------------
User_A |   Team_A   | User_B |   Team_B
User_C |   Team_B   | User_A |   Team_A
User_B |   Team_B   | User_A |   Team_A
User_D |   Team_A   | User_C |   Team_B
User_C |   Team_B   | User_A |   Team_A
User_B |   Team_B   | User_D |   Team_A
User_D |   Team_A   | User_C |   Team_B
```

The same user can be shown as a killer or a victim depends if he killed somebody or died by somebody.

I can show the total kills of users of a **specific Clan** by,

```
SELECT killer AS username, COUNT(killer) AS kills FROM master_tracker
WHERE killerClan = "Team_A"
GROUP BY killer
ORDER BY kills DESC
```

and by the same logic, I can show the total deaths of users of a **specific Clan** by,

```
SELECT victim AS username, COUNT(victim) AS deaths FROM master_tracker
WHERE victimClan = "Team_A"
GROUP BY victim
ORDER BY deaths DESC
```

But... what I want to do is to combine the two queries and show the users' kills and deaths group by their name which can be found in **killer** column in the first case and **victim** column in the second case so ultimately to be able to present their Kills/Deaths Ratio but I need different WHERE causes because in first case their Clan can be found as **killerClan** and in the second case as **victimClan**.

Goal is to have a result like that.

```
username | kills | deaths | kdRatio
-----------------------------------
 User_D  |   2   |    1   |    1
 User_A  |   1   |    3   |   -2
```

All suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select 
    username, 
    sum(kills) kills, 
    sum(deaths) deaths,
    sum(kills) - sum(deaths) kdRatio
from (
    select killer username, count(*) kills, 0 deaths 
    from master_tracker 
    where killerClan = 'TeamA'
    group by killer
    union all 
    select victim, 0, count(*) 
    from master_tracker 
    where victimClan = 'TeamA'
    group by victim
) t
group by username
order by kdRatio desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My database column names are **killer, killerClan, victim, victimClan** I have to get the username by combining **killer** and **victim** columns where the user is the same. Also, I need to present results according to specific Clan which can also be found as killerClan or victimClan. I don't have kills and killed columns so to find the total Kills and Deaths I have to COUNT rows where Clan name is ex. Team_A and Group by user.

Comment: @GeorgeTagas: yes. The above query should produce the expected results (ie, number of kills and deaths per user). Please try the query.

Comment: I'm getting the correct sum(kills) while I'm getting sum(deaths) only when user has been killed by a user of the TeamA, not from users of other teams.

Comment: @GeorgeTagas: my bad. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted! I was starting to lose hope because this post was tagged as similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139000/multiple-query-same-table-but-in-different-columns-mysql) by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) but I really couldn't find my way out of this issue looking there.