# Can I run a separate query on each row instead of printing all the data with a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, row, echo

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,SELECT `date`,`name`,`surname`, COUNT(*) AS abc FROM `trial` WHERE `name`='asd' GROUP BY `date`,`name`,`surname` ORDER BY `date` DESC);

<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) : ?>
     <td><?php echo $row['abc']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['Can I print a value returned from a different query, not abc? ']; ?></td>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can I run a separate query for the second row instead?

Comment: You can run another query, or you can join the two queries into a single query.

Comment: I generally recommend joining.

Comment: What is the other query you want to get the value from?

Comment: Can you give an example of a simple query that can be used like this?

Comment: If you show the other query, I can show how to combine them.

Comment: I'll run this for my first row
$query = mysqli_query($conn,SELECT `date`,`name`,`surname`, COUNT(*) AS abc FROM `trial` WHERE `name`='asd' GROUP BY `date`,`name`,`surname` ORDER BY DATE`date` DESC); 
AND 
I'll run this for my second row
$query = mysqli_query($conn,SELECT `date`,`name`,`surname`, COUNT(*) AS ayt FROM `trial` WHERE `name`='opr' GROUP BY `date`,`name`,`surname` ORDER BY DATE`date` DESC);

Comment: Edit the question, it's unreadable in comments.

Comment: How are the two queries related?

Comment: `where name IN ('asd','opr')`?

Comment: Only parts where name = '' will change

Comment: I want to do that.    <td><?php echo $row['abc']; ?></td> and <td><?php echo $row['ayt']; ?></td>
Do I need to run 2 queries for this? Can I get both in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them into a single query that gets both counts for each surname.

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"
    SELECT `date`,`surname`, SUM(name = 'asd') AS asd_count, SUM(name = 'opr') AS opr_count
    FROM `trial` 
    WHERE `name`= IN ('asd', 'opr')
    GROUP BY `date`,`surname`
    ORDER BY `date` DESC");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['asd_count']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['opr_count']; ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

See [multiple query same table but in different columns mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139000/multiple-query-same-table-but-in-different-columns-mysql/33139182#33139182)

You also need to start a new `<tr>` for each row returned by the query.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand very well. The query works fine, but there is a problem. It does not show data with the same date, same last name but different name on the same line.
So it shows as asd_count and opr_count on two different rows down. I want it to appear side by side on the same row.

Comment: They should. But it was missing `<tr>` to start a new row. I added that.

Comment: Not exactly. I did this, but there is a problem with the mysql query. It would be great if I could show it with a photo.

Comment: Give a link to an uploaded screenshot.