# Mysql - Unable to get multiple group column count

Tags: mysql

I want to get group records of my mysql table. Here is database screenshot

[image]

I used this query

```
SELECT url, count(url) AS total_orders 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY url 
ORDER BY COUNT(url) DESC;
```

I got this result

[image]

But I also want to get store wise finance column data that have pending value.

Like

```
cmsapi.myshopify.com have 1 pending order in finance

b09a2a-2.myshopify.com have 1 pending order in finance
```

Actually I want to get result as below screenshot

[image]

How to get this all result in one mysql query ?

Regards

Comment: You can group by multiple columns: `GROUP BY url, finance`

Comment: Why are you unable to do this?

Comment: If you only want to get pending value, use `WHERE finance = 'pending'`. The question isn't clear.

Comment: @Barmar sir actually I want to get one extra column in final result having counts of each store that have finance "pending" only

Comment: If you want to get both the total count and pending count in one query, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139000/multiple-query-same-table-but-in-different-columns-mysql/33139182#33139182

Comment: @Barmar here is the result I want sir: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SNn6.png

Comment: Doesn't the question I linked to show how to do that? `SELECT url, COUNT(*) AS total_orders, SUM(finance = 'pending') AS finance_pending`