# SQL - Grab records within two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, range

I've got the following table structure.

Table 1

```
id  Value   start_date  
1   1000    09-05-2010  
2   2000    10-05-2011  
3   3000    11-05-2012  
4   4000    17-05-2013
5   5000    18-05-2014
```

Looking at this table, I would like to know which value (which will be 3000) will be the correct one for a record in another table with date 01-01-2013.

My challenge is that I'm not able to define which is the last date before the given one (01-01-2013 in my example).

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you also include a definition/sample for the other table?

Comment: It's an Oracle database and launching queries from SQL Developer.

Comment: The other table is as following:

 id Value  start_date 
    1 5000000 01-01-2011 
    2 6000000 01-01-2012
    3 7000000 01-01-2013

Comment: You always look for the latest date in the table that is not after your given date (like 01-01-2013)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 12c+, you can do this as:

```
select t2.*,
       (select t1.value
        from table1 t1
        where t1.date <= t2.date
        order by t1.date
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as value
from table2 t2;
```

In earlier versions, you can use `keep`:

```
select t2.*,
       (select max(t1.value) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc)
        from table1 t1
        where t1.date <= t2.date
       ) as value
from table2 t2;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Your approach - for earlier versions, not in 12c yet - worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can `SELECT` the dates inferior to the one you choose (`eg 01-01-2013`) and use `LIMIT` to get the nearest.

```
SELECT value from my_table WHERE start_date < mydate LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I've got trouble with the given date 'mydate' as it's a date stored in a different table and as it's a relational database I need to add other several tables where the links are established between these two tables.

Comment: You can select your data from multiple tables, or use a JOIN procedure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql