# Display two tables data in single page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables called users and vm_tables. Now I am displaying data from users as below.

```
 $sel_query="Select * from users where account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id'];

<td align="left"><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $row["email_address"]; ?></td>
```

I would like to display data from vm_details also in same table.

Can anyone help me how to merge two tables data please.

Comment: refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql)

Comment: Use [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: You should use  `JOIN`

Comment: @Keerthi let us show your tables structure if there is any common field between both, so use join

Answer (score 0):

One way is to fetch data from 2 tables in 2 separate arrays and merge the arrays into one using array_merge or array_combine functions

Comment: what if both the table has same column name ? array merge will override the values

Answer (score 0):

you can create single table using JOIN and get both table data together (for this you have to have foreign key with ur second table)  or use 2 sql_query arrays n display in one table both are possible.

Answer (score 0):

you could use join

```
Select * from users u
LEFT JOIN vm_details v ON v.common_field=u.common_field
where u.account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id']
```

whereas common_field is identical column on both  table.

Comment: how do you know that both the table has a common field, did he say about that?

Comment: what is the necessary to join two un related tables?

Comment: that is not necessary what if he wants to first show the 1st table data and then below 2nd table data ?

Comment: if her table has two common columns can use this solution... is it ok now @BunkerBoy r u happy :D

Comment: It is all up to her @ Pattatharasu Nataraj do be serious :) (y)

Comment: exactly @BunkerBoy ;) :)