# Search in multiple tables using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I am building an online glossary with PHP and MySQL.
The search page consists of two dropdown-lists and a search field where the user inputs the desired term.

I have created eight tables:

- four for the languages with their variants (e.g. US and UK for English)
- four for the definitions for each language (English definitions, French definitions, etc.).

I am stuck at the point where the user inputs the term to get the desired translation and the corresponding definition.
How I can I build an SQL query that matches the target language and provides a definition depending on the selection in the dropdown-list? 
Here's the code that I have written so far.

**HTML form** - Query File

```html
     <!-- Create Form -->
      <!-- Send data with the 'post' method to the file called 'retrieve.php' -->
      <form action="retrieve.php" method="post">
    
        <!-- Choose source language -->
        <!-- Flex Container, 1st div -->
        <div class="flex-container">
          <!-- Flex Container, 1st div -->
          <div>
          <p class="instruction-frame" id="srclanguage">Source Language<br />
              <!-- Indication for single selection -->
              <span class="smallfont">Select a single language</span></p>
    
              <!-- Adjust the width of the select list-->
              <select class="my_dropdown" name="source" size="5">
                <option cvalue="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="Terms_de">German</option>
                <option value="Terms_us">English - US</option>
                <option value="Terms_uk">English - UK</option>
                <option value="Terms_fr">French</option>
                <option value="Terms_ardz">Arabic - Algeria</option>
                <option value="Terms_arbh">Arabic - Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Terms_artd">Arabic - Chad</option>
                <option value="Terms_arkm">Arabic - Comoros</option>
                <option value="Terms_ardj">Arabic - Djibouti</option>
                <option value="Terms_areg">Arabic - Egypt</option>
                <option value="Terms_arer">Arabic - Eritrea</option>
                <option value="Terms_ariq">Arabic - Iraq</option>
                <option value="Terms_aril">Arabic - Israel</option>
                <option value="Terms_arjo">Arabic - Jordan</option>
                <option value="Terms_arkw">Arabic - Kuwait</option>
                <option value="Terms_arlb">Arabic - Lebanon</option>
                <option value="Terms_arly">Arabic - Libya</option>
                <option value="Terms_armt">Arabic - Malta</option>
                <option value="Terms_armr">Arabic - Mauritania</option>
                <option value="Terms_arma">Arabic - Morocco</option>
                <option value="Terms_arom">Arabic - Oman</option>
                <option value="Terms_arps">Arabic - Palestine</option>
                <option value="Terms_arqa">Arabic - Qatar</option>
                <option value="Terms_arsa">Arabic - Saudi Arabia</option>
                <option value="Terms_arso">Arabic - Somalia</option>
                <option value="Terms_arsd">Arabic - Sudan</option>
                <option value="Terms_arsy">Arabic - Syria</option>
                <option value="Terms_artz">Arabic - Tanzania</option>
                <option value="Terms_artn">Arabic - Tunisia</option>
                <option value="Terms_arae">Arabic - UAE</option>
                <option value="Terms_arye">Arabic - Yemen</option>
              </select>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Flex Container, 2nd div -->
            <div>
              <p class="instruction-frame" id="trgtlanguage">Target Languages<br />
                <!-- Indication for multiple selection -->
                <span class="smallfont">Hold Ctrl for multiple selection</span></p>
                <!-- Allowing multiple selection -->
                <select class="my_dropdown" name="target" size="5" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="Terms_de">German</option>
                <option value="Terms_us">English - US</option>
                <option value="Terms_uk">English - UK</option>
                <option value="Terms_fr">French</option>
                <option value="Terms_ardz">Arabic - Algeria</option>
                <option value="Terms_arbh">Arabic - Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Terms_artd">Arabic - Chad</option>
                <option value="Terms_arkm">Arabic - Comoros</option>
                <option value="Terms_ardj">Arabic - Djibouti</option>
                <option value="Terms_areg">Arabic - Egypt</option>
                <option value="Terms_arer">Arabic - Eritrea</option>
                <option value="Terms_ariq">Arabic - Iraq</option>
                <option value="Terms_aril">Arabic - Israel</option>
                <option value="Terms_arjo">Arabic - Jordan</option>
                <option value="Terms_arkw">Arabic - Kuwait</option>
                <option value="Terms_arlb">Arabic - Lebanon</option>
                <option value="Terms_arly">Arabic - Libya</option>
                <option value="Terms_armt">Arabic - Malta</option>
                <option value="Terms_armr">Arabic - Mauritania</option>
                <option value="Terms_arma">Arabic - Morocco</option>
                <option value="Terms_arom">Arabic - Oman</option>
                <option value="Terms_arps">Arabic - Palestine</option>
                <option value="Terms_arqa">Arabic - Qatar</option>
                <option value="Terms_arsa">Arabic - Saudi Arabia</option>
                <option value="Terms_arso">Arabic - Somalia</option>
                <option value="Terms_arsd">Arabic - Sudan</option>
                <option value="Terms_arsy">Arabic - Syria</option>
                <option value="Terms_artz">Arabic - Tanzania</option>
                <option value="Terms_artn">Arabic - Tunisia</option>
                <option value="Terms_arae">Arabic - UAE</option>
                <option value="Terms_arye">Arabic - Yemen</option>
                </select> 
              </div>
    
              <!-- Position the submit button at the bottom -->
              <div class="button">
                <div class="row" id="button">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Enter your term..." aria-label="Enter your term here">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <!-- Choose different color for the button through 'btn-primary' --> 
                        <!-- type 'submit' to call the file 'retrieve.php' once the user clicks the button -->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
    
            </div>
```

**PHP** - Retrieve File

```
<?php 
        //Connect to the MySQL server with mysqli
  require_once 'login.php';
  $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
  if ($conn->connect_error) 
  {
    echo "Connection to database failed. Please retry later.";
    exit;
  }

        //Reduce length of variable names 
        //Check if mandatory fields have been filled in
  if (isset($_POST['source'])) {
    $source=$_POST['source'];
  }
  else {
    echo"<p class=\"warning\">"."A mandatory field is still empty. Please retry again."."<br />"."<br />"."<a href=\"query.php\">"."<img src=\"stock-home.png\" alt=\"Home\" />"."</a>"."</p>";
    exit;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['target'])) {
    $target=$_POST['target'];
  }
  else {
    echo"<p class=\"warning\">"."A mandatory field is still empty. Please retry again."."<br />"."<br />"."<a href=\"query.php\">"."<img src=\"stock-home.png\" alt=\"Home\" />"."</a>"."</p>";
    exit;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['search'])) { 
    $search=$_POST['search'];
  }
  else {
    echo"<p class=\"warning\">"."A mandatory field is still empty. Please retry again."."<br />"."<br />"."<a href=\"query.php\">"."<img src=\"stock-home.png\" alt=\"Home\" />"."</a>"."</p>";
    exit;
  }

  if (!$search || !$source || !$target) 
  {
    echo"<p class=\"warning\">"."A mandatory field is still empty. Please retry again."."<br />"."<br />"."<a href=\"query.php\">"."<img src=\"stock-home.png\" alt=\"Home\" />"."</a>"."</p>";
    exit;
  }

      //Remove whitespace from beginning and end of the string
  $search=trim($search);

      //Escaping control characters

  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
  {
  $source = addslashes($source);
  $target = addslashes($target);
  $search = addslashes($search);
  }

  //Test

  $query = "SELECT * FROM legal_glossary.determs WHERE ".$source." LIKE '%".$search."%'";
  $result = $conn->query($query);

  $num_results = $result->num_rows;

  echo '<p>Number of entries found: '.$num_results.'</p>';


  ?>
```

**SQL** Definition file

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `ardef` (
  `ardef_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ardef` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ardef_id`),
  KEY `fk_arabic-definitions_idx` (`Terms_id`),
  KEY `ardefix` (`ardef`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_arabic-definitions` FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_id`) REFERENCES `determs` (`Terms_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ardef`
--



CREATE TABLE `arterms` (
  `arterms_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Terms_arma` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_ardz` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arbh` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_artd` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arkm` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_ardj` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_areg` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arer` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_ariq` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_aril` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arjo` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arkw` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arlb` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arly` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_armt` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_armr` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arom` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arps` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arqa` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arsa` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arso` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arsd` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arsy` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_artz` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_artn` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arae` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_arye` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`arterms_id`),
  KEY `fk_arterms_idx` (`Terms_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_arterms` FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_id`) REFERENCES `determs` (`Terms_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `arterms`
--




CREATE TABLE `dedef` (
  `dedef_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dedef` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dedef_id`),
  KEY `fk_german_definitions_1_idx` (`Terms_id`),
  KEY `dedefix` (`dedef`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_german_definitions_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_id`) REFERENCES `determs` (`Terms_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dedef`
--


CREATE TABLE `determs` (
  `Terms_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Terms_de` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Time when record was updated.',
  `Terms_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Time when record was created.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Terms_id`),
  KEY `determ` (`Terms_de`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `endef` (
  `endef_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `endef` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`endef_id`),
  KEY `fk_english-definitions_idx` (`Terms_id`),
  KEY `endefix` (`endef`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_english-definitions` FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_id`) REFERENCES `determs` (`Terms_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;



/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `enterms` (
  `enterms_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Terms_uk` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_us` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`enterms_id`),
  KEY `fk_enterms_1_idx` (`Terms_id`),
  KEY `ukterm` (`Terms_uk`),
  KEY `usterm` (`Terms_us`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_enterms_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_id`) REFERENCES `determs` (`Terms_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `frdef` (
  `frdef_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `frdef` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`frdef_id`),
  KEY `fk_french-definitions_idx` (`Terms_id`),
  KEY `frdefix` (`frdef`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_french-definitions` FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_id`) REFERENCES `determs` (`Terms_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `frterms` (
  `frterms_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Terms_fr` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`frterms_id`),
  KEY `fk_frterms_idx` (`Terms_id`),
  KEY `frterm` (`Terms_fr`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_frterms` FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_id`) REFERENCES `determs` (`Terms_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `frterms`
--

LOCK TABLES `frterms` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `frterms` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `frterms` VALUES (1,'Contrat de mariage',1),(3,'Extrait du casier judiciaire',4),(4,'Registre des marriages',2);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `frterms` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-12-20 16:50:28
```

Comment: Please explain more the objective of your form: a glossary or a translation form? Enter what to get what? Please also provide some data and a working example of desired result per a specified search.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback.

The form allows the user to select the source and the target language.
The user selects the language pair, then inserts a term in the search field and gets the translation of his term.
You enter the term "Perfect", select English as source and French as target from the drop-down lists, and the result should show the following:
Source: Perfect
Target: Parfait.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT \* FROM multiple tables. MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql)

Comment: "I have created eight tables" - why? it should just be one, even if you are relying on different collations.

Comment: @symcbean: I thought that using more tables would provide more flexibility, but thinking about it right now, I realize that it may not be necessary as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised, normalize your database schema to scale with one long table with indicators instead of similarly structured tables of different names. For instance the below translations of *Perfect* will need to cross-match with every other possible pairing:

TranslationTerms

```
TermID Langauge   Variant   Term
1      English    US        Perfect 
2      French     France    Parfait
3      German     Germany   Perfekt
4      Spanish    Spain     Perfecto
5      Swahili    Kenya     Inafaa
6      Arabic     Kuwait    في احسن الاحوال
...
```

TranslationMatches

```
MatchID  SourceTermID  TargetTermID  
1        2             1
2        3             1                 
3        4             1
4        5             1
5        6             1
6        1             2
7        3             2
8        4             2
9        5             2
10       6             2
11       1             3
12       2             3
13       4             3
14       5             3
15       6             3
16       1             4
17       2             4
18       3             4
19       5             4
20       6             4
21       1             5
22       2             5
23       3             5
24       4             5
25       6             5
26       1             6
27       2             6
28       3             6
29       4             6
30       5             6
```

Then in PHP use a [self-join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) query of terms table that both connect to matching table

```
$source = addslashes($source);
$target = addslashes($target);
$search = addslashes($search);

// LIST OF ALL TARGET TERMS
$query = "SELECT trgt.Term 
          FROM TranslationMatches m
          INNER JOIN TranslationTerms src
             ON m.SourceTermID = src.TermID AND src.Language = ?
          INNER JOIN TranslationTerms trgt
             ON m.TargetTermID = trgt.TermID AND trgt.Language = ?
          WHERE src.Term LIKE ?;"

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $source, $target, "%".$search."%")

$stmt->execute($query);
$stmt->store_result();

$num_results = $stmt->num_rows;

echo '<p>Number of entries found: '.$num_results.'</p>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I will check your suggestions and get back to you if I have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Parfait answer, you may want to add extra column "match_percentage" to the TranslationMatches table so that one term can have multiple matches and each match have matching strength or percentage because words in languages rarely have 100% match and have context dependant translation. This way for each term you show the user multiple words that may be the correct translation ordered by match_percentage column.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome, I hope it's helpful for your project.