# doctrine returns to me 49 instead of 7 !! it's result x resultat! it's normal ,?

Tags: doctrine

```
$queryBuilder = $eleveRepository->createQueryBuilder('n');
$queryBuilder->select('COUNT(eleve.nom)')
            ->from(Eleve::class, 'eleve') ;
$totalEleves = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

return $this->render('security/eleve.html.twig' , [
               'formulaire'=> $form->createView(),
               'eleves' => $eleveRepository->findAll() ,
               'totalEleves' => $totalEleves

        ]) ;
```

I only have 7 records, but doctrine is returning me 49

Comment: Try using "getSingleResult()" instead of "getSingleScalarResult()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this:

1) Remove

```
->from(Eleve::class, 'eleve')
```

this is not needed since you create the query builder from the Eleve repository `$eleveRepository->createQueryBuilder('n')`

2) Change the select to:

```
$queryBuilder->select('COUNT(n.nom)')
```

Why this happens:

Calling [**from()**](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.6/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L858) creates a [**Cartesian product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between all Eleve entities:

So you get a result of 7 Eleve x 7 Eleve combinations.
You can see the sql query by doing:

```
$sql = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL();
```

and it will be similar to:

```
SELECT COUNT(a0_.nom) AS sclr_0 FROM eleve a1_, eleve a0_
```

This is equivalent to a [join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql) of eleve table with itself.