# SQL select unique ID from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, datatables

I have multiple SQL tables, for example two tables with employees from office1 and office2. Each employer has an unique ID, which I have. I do not know in office the employer works so I want to select from both tables.

*note* in reality I have up to 50 tables, still with a unique ID.

database name for example employers

```
use employers
SHOW tables;

+---------------------+
| Tables_in_employers |
+---------------------+
| office1             |
| office2             |
+---------------------+

SELECT * FROM `office1`, `office2` WHERE ID=1

Column `ID` in where clause is ambiguous
```

I have seen a solution like this: ([SELECT * FROM multiple tables. MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890071/select-from-multiple-tables-mysql/12890085))

```
SELECT * FROM `office1`, `office2` WHERE office1.ID=1 GROUP BY
```

But that statement only search in the office1 table, while I want to search both tables and only return the row where the ID matches.

Now I tend to use a for loop en go over each table (in python), but before I implement that I wanted to be sure that this can not be done (faster) in pure SQL.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Consider using  a `union`, your example above is producing a cartesian product.

Comment: It is usually bad schema design to have two 'identical' tables.  You have found one of the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union:

```
SELECT ID, office
FROM (select ID, 'office' as 'office1' FROM office1
      union all
      select ID, 'office' as 'office2' FROM office2) allOffices
WHERE ID=1;
```

Or create a view:

```
create view allOffices as 
  select ID, 'office' as 'office1' from office1 
  union all 
  select ID, 'office' as 'office2' from office2;
```

After this your can do:

```
SELECT ID, office
FROM allOffices WHERE ID=1
```

The output will contain the column `ID`, and the columnd `office` with the name that is specified in the `CREATE VIEW`.

NOTE: it is possible that these queries return more than 1 row, if the ID exists in both offices.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I get the follow error: `ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`. This is correct, all tables contain the `ID` column, but they can have additional columns with extra information. Besides this error, with this method I have to know all tables beforehand, it is not possible to union all tables in a database right?

Comment: When you do not know all tabled beforehand, not much is possible at all.  The only thing left is to replace `*` by `ID`, I will edit in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Oke, I think there is no real solution in pure SQL based on your answer, but thank you for your time and explanation. I will accept your answer.